# Проблема с ротацией материалов

Tags: javascript

Вот код:

```
<script>
var interval=setInterval('changeIm()',2000);
function changeIm(){
count=2;
path = {};
path[0]='1txt';
path[1]='2txt';
for(c=0;c<count;c++){
pathe = path[c];
}
my_img.innerHTML = pathe;
}
</script>
<div id='my_img'></div>
```

**Как он должен работать**: пользователь заходит на страницу, ничего не показывается, проходит 2 секунды, печатается 1txt, далее проходит еще 2 секунды, 1txt меняется на 2txt, проходит еще 2 секунды - 2txt меняется на 1txt и т.д.

**Как он работает сейчас**: пользователь заходит на страницу, ничего не показывается, проходит 2 секунды, печатается 2txt, далее ничего не изменяется, сколько бы времени ни прошло.

Вижу проблема в цикле for, он передает последние данные в переменную pathe. Но как её исправить - не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

бррр, зачем все так сложно?

```
<html>
  <body onload="setInterval('changeIm()',2000)">
    <script>
    var count = 0 ;
    var path = ['one','two'] ;
    function changeIm(){
      document.getElementById("my_img").innerHTML = path[count];

      count= count + 1;
      if (count>=path.length) {
        count = 0 ;
      }
    }
    </script>

    <p id='my_img'></p>
  </body>  
 </html>
```

просто сделать глобальной переменную, которая хранит индекс текущего элемента

Answer (score 0):

дело в том, что Вам надо ознакомиться с таким понятием, как замыкания и доступность переменных. Переменная `pathe` впервые у Вас упоминается только в цикле, соответственно, при выходе из цикла она перестаёт быть доступной (её значение) для всего скрипта. поэтому не хватает объявления переменной `pathe` до цикла, чтобы получилось замыкание.

ЗЫ про замыкания можно почитать в этой статье - [Замыкания](http://javascript.ru/basic/closure)

Comment: Никак не могу понять. Читал на habrahabre. Просто тупик какой-то...

Comment: пробовали объявить переменную `pathe` до цикла?

Comment: Пробовал без цикла, пробовал с if'ами, while... Пробовал с php связывать. А как до цикла объявлять? Мы же должны из "c" брать данные по-любому?

Comment: так получается, что Вам нужно следующее - просто 2с, вызвать функцию, определить что именно будет выводиться - прервать выполнение цикла, вернуть это значение в другую функцию, в которой данное содержание подставиться в нужную область. и всё сначала....

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что у вас выводится **1txt**, а через *12мс* **2txt**.
Попробуйте сделать что-то вроде:

```
function changeIm2(pathe){
  my_img.innerHTML = pathe;
}

function changeIm(){
  count=2;
  path = {};
  path[0]='1txt';
  path[1]='2txt';
  for(c=0;c<count;c++){
    setInterval('changeIm2('+path[c]+')',count*2000+c*2000); 
  }
}
```

И слой вида:
    <div id='my_img' onLoad="changeIm()"></div>

Comment: Уже полностью запутался. Могу оплатить работающий вариант. За сколько сможете сделать?

Comment: @nick777, у Вас уже есть работающий вариант. в данном варианте цикл выполняется с прерыванием. текущее значение передаётся параметром другой функции...присмотритесь!)

Comment: Интуитивно понимаю этот скрипт, здесь через setInterval приостанавливаем и передаем path[c] в pathe, но тем не менее - он тоже не работает. Пробовал несколько раз.

Comment: Но немного не понял. Зачем умножать count и c?

Comment: count*2000 - столько задержка ВСЕХ path
c*2000 - столько задержка 2 секунды конкретной записи...

Если не учитывать count, то все path будут появляться одновременно.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
path = [];
path[0] = '1txt';
path[1] = '2txt';
function changeIm(i){
    c = path.length;
    my_img.innerHTML = path[i%c];
    setTimeout(function(){changeIm(i+1);}, 2000);
}
changeIm(0);
</script>
<div id='my_img'></div>
```